# How can I save card data to the Stripe in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I want to save card info to the stripe and with that data, I want to pay later. I am using flutter stripe package, but I didn't find any way to do so.

Comment: Most of the same principles from https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet apply. You'd create your PaymentIntent on the backend with `setup_future_usage` set which will result in the payment method used in the initial payment to be saved to the Customer object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically cannot do that **with Flutter**.

You have to build that on your back-end :

1/ Create a customer : https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create

2/ Create a SetupIntent, with `usage` argument setup to `off_session`
https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create

3/ Charge the customer by creating a subscription or an invoice.

Then you'll be able to charge the customer based on this payment method.

*PS : Be extremely careful, you can only do that for physical products, for digital goods, platforms (iOS, Android) requires you to use their inhouse solution (Google Billing, InApp Purchases...)*